# Passing values of different data types in Method Overloading

Tags: java, overloading

I pass a double value to the method that is being overloaded but it takes it as float and invokes the method for finding area of square. Float values should have an "f" to their end to be considered float right? so why does my program invoke float 'area of square' when it's supposed to invoke 'area of circle'?

```
public class App {
    public void calArea(float a) {
        System.out.println("Area of square is Side x Side : " + a * a);
    }

    public void calArea(float a, float b) {
        System.out.println("Area of rectangle is length x width" + a * b);
    }

    public void calArea(double r) {
        double area = (Math.PI * r * r);
        System.out.println("Area of circle is Radius x Radius x PI : " + area);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        App app = new App();

        app.calArea(5);
    }

}
```

Comment: You don't pass a double, you pass an int.

Comment: Output: Area of square is Side x Side : 25.0

Comment: So when passing, i should specify a decimal point to clarify double from int?

Comment: @Lino Not according the output he specified.

Comment: 5D, 5d or 5.0 would all be doubles, yes.

Comment: Instead of using `double` and `float` to distinguish what areas should be calculated. Just *name them differently*. This will remove a lot of headache when seeing your code. *Will `app.calArea(5)` calculate the area of a circle or a square?*

Comment: Square i suppose

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just post my comment as an answer, because it is the only way to resolve your problem without casting.

Instead of using `double` and `float` to distinguish what areas should be calculated. Just *name them differently*. This will remove a lot of headache when seeing your code.

> *Will `app.calArea(5)` calculate the area of a circle or a square?*

So just change your code to this:

```
public class App {
    public void calAreaSquare(double a) {
        System.out.println("Area of square is Side x Side : " + a * a);
    }

    public void calAreaRectangle(double a, double b) {
        System.out.println("Area of rectangle is length x width" + a * b);
    }

    public void calAreaCircle(double r) {
        double area = (Math.PI * r * r);
        System.out.println("Area of circle is Radius x Radius x PI : " + area);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        App app = new App();

        app.calAreaCircle(5);
    }
}
```

I would also suggest just using `double` only, for the enhanced precision.

Comment: Yes, this way its a better code structure but i was trying to get my head around method overloading and type promotion topic in java which is why i named the methods similar. Thanks for the answer

Comment: @Stewie you're welcome. I guess this is just not the right use case for method overloading.

Answer (score 2):

Simplest way to invoke method of 'area of circle' is just by calling from main method as "**app.calArea(5d);**". By writing 5d or 5.0d area of circle method will be called because the value 5d is considered as double. And if you want to invoke method of 'area of square', you can do it in either way by (1) **app.calArea(5f);** or (2) **app.calArea(5)**.

So, if you want to continue with your method overloading and invoke 'area of circle' you can do it in this way

```
public class App {
    public void calArea(float a) {
        System.out.println("Area of square is Side x Side : " + a * a);
    }

    public void calArea(float a, float b) {
        System.out.println("Area of rectangle is length x width" + a * b);
    }

    public void calArea(double r) {
        double area = (Math.PI * r * r);
        System.out.println("Area of circle is Radius x Radius x PI : " + area);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        App app = new App();

        app.calArea(5d);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5) are some quotes from the language spec that explains this behaviour.

> **Section 15.12.2.5 Choosing the Most Specific Method**
>
> If more than one member method is both accessible and applicable to a
>   method invocation, it is necessary to choose one to provide the
>   descriptor for the run-time method dispatch. The Java programming
>   language uses the rule that the *most specific* method is chosen. The
>   informal intuition is that one method is more specific than another **if
>   any invocation handled by the first method could be passed on to the
>   other one without a compile-time error.**

In your case, both `calArea(float)` and `calArea(double)` are applicable for a single `int` argument (`int` can be converted to either `float` or `double` through a primitive widening conversion).

Now the compiler needs to decide which is more specific. In the end, the compiler chose `calArea(float)` because it is more specific than `calArea(double)`.

Every call that is applicable to `calArea(float)` is applicable to `calArea(double)` (implicit primitive widening conversion from `float` to `double`), but not vice versa (you need a cast to convert from `double` to `float`).

Therefore the compiler chose the `calArea(float)` overload.

Comment: Good explanation. Will keep this in mind. Thanks for taking the time to answer.

Answer (score 1):

to answer "why does my program invoke float 'area of square' when it's supposed to invoke 'area of circle'?"

> This is because the exact matched method which accept int argument is not found hence based on widening, nearest method that matched is called(here its float)
>   widening happens in below order
>   byte - > short - > int - > long - > float - > double

in your case its (int - > long - > float - > double) 
as you are passing int argument hence nearest match is a method that accepts float argument hence calArea(float a) is called

[to check this try including a method that accepts long argument and you will see it will get a chance to execute instead of earlier method that accepts float argument]

e.g

1. public void calArea(int a) {
   System.out.println("int");
   }
2. public void calArea(long a) {
   System.out.println("long");
   }
3. public void calArea(float a) {
   System.out.println("float");
   }
4. public void calArea(double a) {
   System.out.println("double");
   }

method call is - calArea(5);
case 1: lets say no method commented
here method accepting int argument will be called.

case 2: now comment /remove first method (accepting int argument) 
here method accepting long argument will be called.

case 3: now again comment method 1 and 2 method
here method accepting float argument will be called.
and so on...

Answer (score -2):

As you are passing int value not double.... so 'area of square' is being calculated. For 'area of circle' you have to pass decimal value as argument while calling the function.

Comment: 'are of square requires a `float` though. And floats are decimals too